# Navigation Back & MVVM - How to refresh WP8 page databinding

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, mvvm, windows-phone-8

I'm doing a WP8 App (C#/XAML).

In my view I specify a button, which contect is set by binding with a callback, for the start of an app, when the VM is not fully loaded.

MVVM looks like:

```
ViewModel
---------
 + Model
   -----
    +Property
```

And is created in `App.xaml.cs` like this:

```
public static MainViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            if (viewModel == null)
            {
                viewModel = new MainViewModel();
            }
            return viewModel;
        }
    }
```

And set to the page as datacontext in contructor of the page:

```
DataContext = App.ViewModel;
```

And button:

```
<Button x:Name="btn" Content="{Binding Model.Property, FallBackValue='click to load'}" .../>
```

- At the start, the `btn` does not have a value to put in it's content, because model is empty.
- When the `btn` is clicked, it loads the model. It fills model with data and navigates to another page which shows that data.
- And when i navigate back (through hardware back button) I'd like `btn` to use the value from binding instead of a fallback, because the value is already set. But It doesn't use it and still uses the one provided by FallbackValue argument of binding.

**How to ensure, that the page "refreshes" an uses actual values provided by ViewModel?**

Comment: Can you add more depth to this part of the question, because I don't understand what you mean. Quote:" it jumps back to first page and the contect of the button is still click to load instead of the value of Model.Property..."

Comment: edited it. hope it is more readable now. I'm putting an allnighter and my social interaction skills are pretty much depleted, so it is sometimes hard to understand me.

Comment: You will probably have to use the OnNavigatedFrom function to send your filled object back to your mainpage.

Comment: Well, the ViewModel containing Model is static and binded by DataContext property to the page.

Comment: But are you sure, these items are still "alive" when you leave the page by navigating back to your mainpage, and that the garbage collector doesn't dispose of the viewmodel/model even tho their static, its something you could check

Comment: Yup, it is. Just tested it by navigating from the second page and showing the property in messagebox popped up in `OnNavigatedTo` event. It's there and exists. Thinking about it, it could not even have been true, because the object of the page was created and had the viewmodel set as datacontext (same as the second page) and when the navigation back occurs, the page is not recreated, just showed from memory. But the binding should reflect all the changes that happened in the model. But maybe I'm wrong about it reflecting the changes and i need to refresh the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ahh, ok found solution to my problem myself.

## THE PROBLEM

If you're using static Datacontext (if the Viewmodel class you use is created as static), then when you navigate back to the page, the databinding won't update (at least that is how it was in my case).

I use same datacontext (ViewModel containing multiple models and inside some collections and properties) for multiple pages. But when I navigated back to the page through hardware back button, the databinding was not updated.

The content of a button/textblock is stuck at the old value, even though you changed it to some new one.

## Solution

Override the OnNavigatedTo Method, and set databinding there instead in contructor. This way you can be sure, that the databinding is always "fresh" and updated.

**Inside the `page` class in code-behind (the `.xaml.cs` file sticked to your `.xaml` page) write this:**

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
   base.OnNavigatedTo(e);        //can be left out, base method is empty
   DataContext = null;           //setting datacontext empty at first
   DataContext = App.ViewModel;  //and setting it to the static ViewModel i created
}
```

This way, the `DataContext` is always first set to `null`, when I come to the page (so that the old values clean and there is nothing to bind from).

And shortly after that, i put the original DataContext back, so it has something to bind from again.

**The step with `null` is necessary, because i need the datacontext property to change, otherwise if I just point again at the same obect that is already set as dataContext, nothing will happen.**

Answer (score 2):

I guess your ViewModel would be implementing INotifyPropertyChanged. To refresh the data binding you just need to raise property change event implemented in your model. In OnNavigatedTo event of your page check if Model is empty or not. If not raise property change

In your view model

```
 public class ViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
 {   
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion
  }
```

In your page

```
  protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
  {
        if (App.ViewModel != null)
            App.ViewModel.NotifyPropertyChanged("Name of property");
  }
```

Comment: That's good, but won't it just refresh a single value in the model?

Comment: I already solved it and was just finishing my own answer as you posted your answer. :) In the end we came to similar conclusions. :)